# How to prevent stored XSS Attack?

Tags: xss

Is there a way we can prevent unauthorized people changing google map api key on the live running site?

In my site, I have included a google map api key.

Some times, I see that the google map key is modified/changed to something else. I suspect a XSS attack on my site and key is google map key is being changed.

Can anyone explain me how to prevent from XSS attack?

Comment: Their is no way to change google maps api key untill someone have access to your server. Or may be their is some fault with your implementation. Can you show us how you are using the api key.